# Reading MachineGuid with TRegistry

Tags: c++builder

I am trying to read the MachineGuid from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography` in the Registry. I have looked at a couple of postings about doing this and based my code on them.

I have the following code in a button `OnClick()` event for testing:

```
AnsiString S = "MachineGuid: ";
TRegistry* Registry = new TRegistry(KEY_READ);
try {
    Registry->RootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    // False because we do not want to create it if it doesn’t exist
    Registry->OpenKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography", false);
    // Registry->OpenKeyReadOnly("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography");
    if (!Registry->ValueExists("MachineGuid")) {
        S += String("Key not found!");
    } else {
        S += Registry->ReadString("MachineGuid");
    }
} __finally
{
    delete Registry;
}
Memo2->Lines->Add(S);
```

The problem is that `Registry->ValueExists("MachineGuid")` always reports `false` whether I use `OpenKey()` or `OpenKeyReadOnly()`. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is the first time I am using `TRegistry`.

Using: C++ Builder 11.3 Community Edition

Comment: Did you get it working? If not, please add any additional information you have and I'll see if I can cover that in my answer too.

Comment: I tried your two options of code below, and both worked, gave the same info back. I am running a 64bit OS (Win10), so couldn't test against a 32bit OS. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, Until recently I was using C++ Builder v5 myself. :)

Comment: Cool! A 32/64 OS isn't the issue. It's running a 32 bit app in that will select the 32 bit view over the registry by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `MachineGuid` value is only available in the [64-bit application data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/32-bit-and-64-bit-application-data-in-the-registry) in the registry.

You can solve that by requesting access rights to the 64-bit *view* over the registry. This will work no matter if your application is compiled for 32 or 64 bit:

```cpp
TRegistry* Registry = new TRegistry(KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
```

Example:

```cpp
#include <memory>

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    System::String S = _D("MachineGuid");

    auto Registry = std::make_unique<TRegistry>(KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
    try {
        Registry->RootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
        if (Registry->OpenKeyReadOnly(_D("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography"))) {
            if (!Registry->ValueExists(S)) {
                S += _D(": Key not found!");
            } else {
                S += _D(": ") + Registry->ReadString(S);
            }
        } else {
            S += _D(": OpenKeyReadOnly failed");
        }
    } catch (...) {
        S += _D(": Exception");
    }
    Memo2->Lines->Add(S);
}
```

---

Since I mainly use C++ Builder 4 myself, I was curious about how to solve it in that environment but that version of `TRegistry` doesn't seem to support access rights (there was probably no need back in the 90's). Here's a workaround for really old BCB versions:

```cpp
#ifndef KEY_WOW64_64KEY
#define KEY_WOW64_64KEY 0x0100
#endif

class MyReg {
public:
    MyReg(HKEY hKeyParent, LPCWSTR lpSubKey, DWORD ulOptions, REGSAM samDesired)
    {
        LONG rv =
            RegOpenKeyExW(hKeyParent, lpSubKey, ulOptions, samDesired, &hKey);
        if (rv != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            throw Exception(String("RegOpenKeyExW failed ") + GetLastError());
    }

    ~MyReg() { RegCloseKey(hKey); }

    String ReadString(LPCWSTR lpValueName)
    {
        WCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD cbData = sizeof buf;

        LONG rv = RegQueryValueExW(hKey, lpValueName, 0, NULL,
                                   reinterpret_cast<PBYTE>(buf), &cbData);
        if (rv != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            throw Exception(String("RegGetValueW failed ") + GetLastError());

        buf[cbData / sizeof(WCHAR)] = L'\0';
        return String(buf);
    }

private:
    MyReg(const MyReg&);            // no copying
    MyReg& operator=(const MyReg&); // no copying

    HKEY hKey;
};

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) {
    MyReg mr(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography", 0,
             KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY);

    String res = mr.ReadString(L"MachineGuid");

    Memo2->Lines->Add(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did modify the MyReg calling Proc. to include a try...catch block for the Exception thrown in the class.

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::Button2Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    String res = String("MachineGUID: ");
    try {
        MyReg mr(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography", 0,
            KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY);

        res += mr.ReadString(L"MachineGuid");

    } catch (Exception &e) {
        res += e.Message;
    }
    Memo1->Lines->Add(res);
}
```